# Rails 3 route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am updating to apply dmarkow's suggestions.

in my routes.rb:

```
  resources :userhome do

    member do
      get :edit_profile_picture
    end

    member do
      post :update_profile_picture
    end

  end
```

rake routes result:

```
edit_profile_picture_userhome
update_profile_picture_userhome
```

the link in the user home page:

```
<%= link_to "update profile picture", edit_profile_picture_userhome_path(@user) %>
```

controller:

```
  def edit_profile_picture
    @user = current_user
  end
```

error message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit_profile_picture", :controller=>"userhome"}
```

I missed the fact that i didn't change the name of my view to match my controller and route. I'm going to follow naming conventions more closely to help me avoid this kind of mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a `Userhome` ID or object to your path. Assuming that the currently-displayed `Userhome` is `@userhome`:

```
<%= link_to "update profile picture", profile_picture_userhome_path(@userhome) %>
```

Comment: Hi, @dmarkow. Thanks. I thought i would just use current_user in the view and the controller since only the current_user can change his/her profile picture. Following your suggestion, i added the controller method and updated the link. Getting same error.

Comment: Just use `profile_picture_userhome_path(current_user)` instead. What action is the `<%= link_to ... %>` being used in? `index` or `show`?

Comment: Then your `edit` action is where you should have the `@user = current_user`, not your `profile_picture` action (if you do it that way).

Comment: ah man... my view file name didn't match the controller and routes. So sorry to take your time up on an error like that. Going to follow naming conventions more intentionally. Thanks.